# PHP Memory Limit vs. WP Memory Limit

Tags: memory

I'm using [TPC! Memory Usage Settings](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/) to monitor my installation's memory usage.

The plugin displays 'WP Memory Limit' which I know is set by the `wp-config.php`. It also displays 'PHP Memory Limit' which I'm guessing is set by the server host in the `php.ini`

This may be a dumb question, but is the 'PHP Memory Limit' the amount of memory I could possibly dedicate to 'WP Memory Limit'?

For instance, if I have a 'PHP memory limit' of  `1000MB`, can I (should I) set my wp memory limit to `1000MB`?

Sidenote: The site is for a big website with lots of different operations, so many (necessary) plugins are installed and many users (up to 10) can be on making edits at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp-config.php` sets the memory limit for the specific WordPress site which has that file. `php.ini` will effect your whole server. The `php.ini` is the parent setting, and so you can set WP to whatever you want within `php.ini`'s range.

It's also importan to note there is a `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` where you can define a max amount of memory WP should use, especially if you have plugins gobbling up all the memory.