# Set WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT higher than PHP.ini memory_limit

Tags: php, memory, configuration, php.ini

I've read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP), but I want to ask if I have understood this correctly.

We have a server in which WordPress admin needed more memory. The PHP `memory_limit`, in PHP.ini, is set to 256M, and so was `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` in wp-includes/default-constants.php. There is a large amount of pages, and I think we will end up automatically delete pages that are older than a certain treshold, but as a quickfix I increased the memory.

I set the `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` to 512M, and that works. The way I understood the documentation is that WordPress will be allowed to use 512M instead of PHPs `memory_limit`, which is set to 256M.

So, is it right that `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` overrides PHPs `memory_limit`?
It is able to use more memory than PHP is configured to use?

It certainly seems that way on our server now, but I want to be sure it is not something else going on.

EDIT: According to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131179/php-memory-limit-vs-wp-memory-limit?rq=1) answer, I can set the wp memory within the limit of php.inis limit. But that doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

The true maximum is ultimately up to the host - they can impose whatever limits they wish. But even so, you can try with `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT`, which is the memory limit WordPress sets at runtime for any given request.

`WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` is only applied in certain situations, either for administrators in the backend (users with the capability `manage_options`), or for image resizing/other intensive operations.

Comment: I used `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` because I only need this in admin mode :) But I am correct in saying that `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` is the actual limit, as long as it is larger than `memory_limit`?

Comment: I also did an edit to the post at the bottom :)

Comment: `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT` is just a value (default `256M`) that WordPress uses to  `ini_set( 'memory_limit' )` for administrators in the backend. If you want to know how exactly PHP handles memory, limits, INI files and runtime ini settings, you're much better off asking on Stackoverflow/PHP-specific channels.